# not work nested route react app(when page refresh) , after depoly on netlify

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I createed a nested route on my react app, then i deployed app on Netlify.
but the nested route not workig after refreshing the page on Netlify(that is okay on my localhost)

note1 : i add _redirects file inside public folder and write on

```
/* /index.html 200
```

note2 : and i add .htaccess file in root app

note3 : i get error in colsole after refresh in nested route
er :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <BrowserRouter basename="/">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route  path="/register/:nested" component={Nested} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Nested.js

```
const Nested = () =>{
    return <div>
        <p>Nedted</p>
    </div>
}
export default Nested;
```

Header.js

```
    const Header = () =>{
        return <header>
                <NavLink to='/register/nestedroute'>Nested</NavLink>
             <NavLink to='/login'>Login</NavLink>
             <NavLink to='/register'>Register</NavLink>
            <NavLink exact to='/'>Home</NavLink>
        </header>
    }
    export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/register/:nested" component={Nested} />
    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: pls check https://612cd00d52fc02000855c244--mystifying-mestorf-4d45a5.netlify.app/register/nestedroute/